# Using the rest of the website while modal is open

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am facing a problem that i failed to find a full solution for;

I have an option for the user to open an "information" modal while he is filling a form.
I need the user to be able to continue to fill the form while the "information" modal is open, so he will be able to use the data in this modal while filling the form.

So far i came across several half answers that did not help my problem.
For the moment i only use this CSS code for my modal:

```
#tokenModal {
    position: absolute;
    top:21px;
    left: 0px;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    width: auto;;
}


#tokenModal > .modal-dialog {
    width: 400px;
}
```

This CSS code allows me to click on inputs in the form such as checkboxes or "select" inputs but i am not able to write any text in the text inputs.

also the model configuration in the HTML is:

```
<div id="tokenModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Label123" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
```

Is there a way to accomplish my needs or should i use an alternative for the solution?

Comment: Why do you need a modal ? Why don't you show an informational message ? Or a popup ?

Comment: @Weedoze Pop-up is not an option. the browsers are blocking it. the information itself is a table so i wouldn't be able to fit it in the form

Comment: Add an informational message on top of the table